# Multiple if conditions check in single button click

Tags: c#

My C# code is something like as follows.

```
    if(TextBox1.Text.Length > 5)
    {
    if(TextBox2.Text.Length > 5)
    {
    if(TextBox3.Text.Length > 5)
    {
    if(TextBox4.Text.Length > 5)
    {
    //Action to pass to the next stage.
    }
    else
    {
    error4.text = "Textbox4 value should be minimum of 5 characters.";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    error3.text = "Textbox3 value should be minimum of 5 characters.";
    }
    }

else
{
error2.text = "Textbox2 value should be minimum of 5 characters.";
}
}
else
{
error1.text = "Textbox1 value should be minimum of 5 characters.";
}
```

1) In the above kind of sample. I am using nested If-Else concept where on button click, if TextBox1 value is less than 5 is moves to else part and shows the error1 value but it will not check for further errors.

2) If I change If conditions to step by step If conditions then it will not work for me because the action must be done only if all the IF conditions satisfies.

3) If I use && operator to check all conditions I will not get individual error to each "error label"

How can I check multiple IF conditions on a single button click?

**My original code**

```
if (checkavail == "available")
        {
            if (name.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                if (email.Text.Length > 5)
                {
                    if (password1.Text.Length > 7 && password1.Text == password2.Text)
                    {
                        if (alternate.Text.Contains("@") && alternate.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            if (question.Text.Length > 0)
                            {
                                if (answer.Text.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    Response.Redirect("next_page.aspx");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    error5.Text = "Please enter your security answer";
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                error4.Text = "Please enter your security question";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            error3.Text = "Invaild alternate email address";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        error2.Text = "Password should be minimum 8 characters and must match confirm password";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    error1.Text = "Email address should be minimum 6 characters";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                error.Text = "Please enter your name";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            error1.Text = "This email address is already taken. Please try another";
        }
```

I need the Redirect action to be done upon satisfying all conditions. If more than one error was found each error should get each error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all. I found my answer in below manner

```
string p1, p2, p3, p4;
        if (TextBox1.Text.Length > 5)
        {
            p1 = "pass";
            Label1.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Textbox1 value should be minimum 5 characters.";
            p1 = "fail";
        }
        if (TextBox2.Text.Length > 5)
        {
            p2 = "pass";
            Label2.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "Textbox2 value should be minimum 5 characters.";
            p2 = "fail";
        }
        if (TextBox3.Text.Length > 5)
        {
            p3 = "pass";
            Label3.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Label3.Text = "Textbox3 value should be minimum 5 characters.";
            p3 = "fail";
        }
        if (TextBox4.Text.Length > 5)
        {
            p4 = "pass";
            Label4.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Label4.Text = "Textbox4 value should be minimum 5 characters.";
            p4 = "fail";
        }
        if (p1 == "pass" && p2 == "pass" && p3 == "pass" && p4 == "pass")
        {
            Status.Text = "All pass";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a function that just handles the error messages. Return an Enumerable from this function. Then you can format your if-statements like this and it will return an Enumerable:

```
private IEnumerable GetErrors()
{
    if (TextBox1.Text.Length > 5) { yield return "Textbox1 minimum bla bla"; }
    if (TextBox2.Text.Length > 5) { yield return "Textbox2 minimum bla bla"; }
    if (TextBox3.Text.Length > 5) { yield return "Textbox3 minimum bla bla"; }
}
```

Make another function that handles your non-error message logic and just perform an if-statement to see if there were zero errors or not:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    var errors = GetErrors();
    if (errors.Count == 0)
        Response.Redirect("next_page.aspx");
    else
        error.Text = "Please fix your errors";
}
```

Comment: Void function does not return value, class can return only one value. So, how this will work?

Comment: Make a new function that checks for errors and returns an Enumerable. You need to rearrange all of your code because those nested if-statements are painful to deal with